# How long after canceling test orders does it reflect in my app

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, in-app-billing

I created a google app, I put it on the play store, and now I am testing inapp purchases with my test account. But then I cancel my purchase so to test how cancellations propagate. But cancellations are not reflected in the app. I can still use my test account with full access to the goods in question. I am using managed products.

It's a whole lot of code so it would be outrageous to post it all here. But I have reviewed my code over and over, and it's doing the right thing. In fact here is a snippet: when a user first launch the app, I check for outstanding purchase and change the state of the good in question as follows

```
Purchase premiumPurchase = inventory.getPurchase(SKU_PREMIUM);
boolean value = (premiumPurchase != null && verifyDeveloperPayload(premiumPurchase) && 0 == premiumPurchase.getPurchaseState());
setLockStateOfPremiumPurchase(this, value);
```

So I am now wondering if the cancellation has propagated to my app. In other words: how long does it take google to change their database so that when I check the inventory, it returns `not purchased`? Or perhaps I am doing this wrong: should I be checking for something else?

When I look at the original json purchase state is `0`

Answer (score 0):

After you cancelled the order in Google Wallet, you need to wait from 5 min to couple hours to get data synchronized back to your device. I'm not sure what it depends on. You just need to wait.

Sometimes it helps to restart the device after you received a confirmation e-mail. After restarting, the device registers itself in Google Play anew and purchases cache gets updated faster.